# Creating GeoTIFF from TIFF image?

Tags: coordinate-system, arcmap, geotiff-tiff, georeferencing, mars

I have a TIFF file that is 2880x1440 pixels. It is a global map in simple cylindrical projection (i.e., each pixel is a 1/8th degree square):

> If the uppermost leftmost pixel has coordinates x = 1, y = 1, then
>
> north latitude (deg) = (720.5 - x) / 8
>
> east longitude (deg) = (y + 0.5) / 8

I'd like to use the projection information to make a GeoTIFF that I can load into ArcMap.

Is that possible or do I need to create a world file instead?

Note also that it is a map of Mars, so I will use the Mars2000 coordinate system (available in ArcMap).

Comment: Create a world file http://webhelp.esri.com/arcims/9.3/General/topics/author_world_files.htm, that will be recognized by most GIS software. You can do it in Notepad if you're not keen on scripting, save the file with the same name as the image (as text) and change extension to tfw. How many of these do you have to do? Do you have any scripting ability?

Comment: It appears the trusty ArcGIS 9.3 page has just gone dead, the ArcGIS 10 page is http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/raster-and-images/world-files-for-raster-datasets.htm - more verbose than the original. Read about world files with descriptive pictures: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_file

Comment: Thanks the articles are good. It is just unclear to me how to compute the map units that go into the word file. How do I compute these from the projection information? Thanks.

Comment: The origin is the upper left coordinate, the cell size is 1/8th of a degree divided by the number of columns (x) and rows (y) which is 0.0000434028 X and -0.0000868056 Y (Y is usually negative). This makes your world file for the given x = 1 and y = 1 
0.0000434028
0
0
-0.0000868056
89.9375
0.1875 provided the image isn't rotated.

Comment: Thanks. I'm still a bit confused. What if the coordinate system is supposed to be referenced to a sphere with radius=3400000 meters? That should be contained in the world file information as well, correct?

Comment: The coordinate system is related to the georeference... consider a wold map, it is rectangular but the Earth (despite what the flat-earthers believe) is sort-of spherical, so to with Mars. As your units are degrees (or decimals thereof) the portrayal as a flat or spheroid is a matter of modelling. Your coordinate system contains a reference to the spheroid and datum (where to start counting from).